# A good article on modern CPU features/performance optimizations?

Tags: performance, optimization, architecture, hardware

After reading [an article](http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=1814327) on virtual memory implications on application performance (and hence design) I once again realize how little I actually know about today's computer architecture. I have but a vague idea of what are caches, pipelines, branch prediction algorithms, how memory buses work, and probably dozens of other artifacts that could greatly improve my program performance if I only knew about them.

For my defense I can say that I alredy knew what VM (virtual memory) was and how it worked, though I'm ashamed that I didn't think of the implications before.

So... can anyone recommend any reading on the subject(s)? I'd vastly prefer online articles that can be read for free - but if you know a good book, don't hesitate to add that too!

P.S. I would also be interested how these lessons affect modern high-level environments like .NET, which is my primary residence.

Comment: +1. Sorry I can't help you, but thanks for asking the question because now I get to learn a bit more too.

Comment: If you are not developing operating system or something similar, you don't have to deal with these issues (and you even *can't*, because this is a closed layer of the software architecture). Other side, everyone should know how does different processor, VM, paging, 64- vs 32-bit etc. work.

Comment: @ern0 - Of course, the OS has a fair bit of control over your app - like it can stop it at any time, mess with your VM, etc. But every once in a while you have a CPU core all to yourself, so it only makes sense to try and do as much as possible while you still can.

Answer (score 2):

Just found [this PDF](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf) by Ulrich Drepper, titled "What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory". Haven't read it, but looks spot on!

Answer (score 2):

Here's something about [sse](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/sseintro.aspx?display=Print).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at these guides by Intel and AMD:

- Intel(R) 64 and IA-32 Architectures Optimization Reference Manual ([PDF](http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/manual/248966.pdf) 4.5MB)
- Software Optimization Guide for AMD Family 15h Processors ([PDF](http://support.amd.com/us/Processor_TechDocs/47414.pdf) 1.9MB)

It's more focused on C/C++ however. But many optimizations should work on .NET too.